# Android Emulator

Tags: android, emulation

I'd like to choose the emulator to simulate the testing of my android app but when I hit run, eclipse opens a new window with a new emulator. How can I make eclipse run on the emulator that is already open?

Comment: Check your run configuration, you're probably pointing to a different AVD than the one you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its better to check your run configuration. Check target tab, its sure that your target avd doesn't match your running emulator.

Do one thing, make emulator selection manual instead of automatic. It will let you choose desired emulator or device when there are more than one avds available